# User Interface Issue android

Tags: android, android-layout

i am making android **UI** (using Relative Layout)in which, i need to set one banner whose size is `306 x 51`. i have set it as center of screen. and it getting displayed well in some android mobile screen but when i run in tablet then display is like:

[image]

as shown in the image, space are remain left and right side. so what i do for it?

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/page1_11"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/login_rellay_01" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:src="@drawable/page1_1"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Shanesh COLORS App"
            android:textSize="13dp" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#49515F"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_rellay_01" android:id="@+id/login_rellay_02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/page1_4"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="SIGN IN"
            android:textSize="13dp" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/page1_2"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/page1_3"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>



    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/login_rellay_03" android:layout_below="@+id/login_rellay_02"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:src="@drawable/page1_5"
            android:id="@+id/imgv_page1_5" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
        <!-- <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/imgv_page1_5" 
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:src="@drawable/page1_6" 
            android:id="@+id/imgv_page1_6" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" /> -->
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/login_rellay_03" android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/login_rellay_02" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="SIGN IN "
                android:textSize="13dp" android:id="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_1"
                android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="with your "
                android:id="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_2" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_1"
                android:textSize="13dp" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Shanesh Colors"
                android:id="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_3" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_2"
                android:textSize="13dp" android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:textColor="#000000" />
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text=" App Account "
                android:id="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_4" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_3"
                android:textSize="13dp" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/login_rellay_04" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:gravity="center" android:layout_below="@+id/login_rellay_03"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_width="306dp" android:background="#FFFFFF" android:id="@+id/imgv_page1_6"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />



        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/login_rellay_04" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center">
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="User Name:"
                android:id="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_5" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_1"
                android:textSize="11dp" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="#49515F" />

            <EditText android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_5" />



        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/login_rellay_05" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/login_rellay_04">
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:text=" Password:"
                android:id="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_5" 
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_1"
                android:textSize="11dp" 
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="#49515F" />

            <EditText android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_5" />



        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/login_rellay_06" 
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/login_rellay_05" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:textColor="#000000"
                      android:text="No Account?"

                      android:textStyle="bold"
                      android:textSize="11dp" 
                      android:id="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_9" 

                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView android:text="Sign Up" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:id="@+id/login_txvx_signup_account" 
          android:textColor="#8891A2" 
          android:textStyle="bold" 
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_9"
          android:textSize="11dp" 
         /></RelativeLayout>
         <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/login_rellay_07" 

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/login_rellay_06" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

         <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/login_txvx_signup_account"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:textColor="#49515F" 
                android:textSize="11dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text=" Remember User Name and Password?" 
          />

          </RelativeLayout>





    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/login_rellay_08" 

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/login_rellay_04" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

          <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:src="@drawable/page1_8"
                     />
          </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem that you're facing and what help do you need? I understood the left and right side but what is it that you want us to help you out with?

Comment: actually i need those banner in entire width of screen.so what i do? i  need to increment my banner size? or other parameter that help me to allow this?

Comment: Please also check my layout file that i have pasted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@zam664 is right ... u should never use fixed widths for Layouts.. try managing them by padding, margins etc.

Use LinearLayout too to manage horizontal children with non-fixed width..

anyway... i modified ur xml a little ... i could not test it fully as i did not have the images/resources u have used in it.. but give it a try.

Replace the whole xml with the following. ...

**Note: a have just changed it a little to give you idea ... u should modify it further if that works**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:background="@drawable/page1_11"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/login_rellay_01" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:src="@drawable/page1_1"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Shanesh COLORS App"
        android:textSize="13dp" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#49515F"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_below="@+id/login_rellay_01" android:id="@+id/login_rellay_02"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/page1_4"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="SIGN IN"
        android:textSize="13dp" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/page1_2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/page1_3"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />


</RelativeLayout>



<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/login_rellay_03" android:layout_below="@+id/login_rellay_02"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:src="@drawable/page1_5"
        android:id="@+id/imgv_page1_5" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    <!-- <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/imgv_page1_5" 
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:src="@drawable/page1_6" 
        android:id="@+id/imgv_page1_6" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" /> -->
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/login_rellay_03" android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_rellay_02" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="SIGN IN "
            android:textSize="13dp" android:id="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_1"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="with your "
            android:id="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_2" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_1"
            android:textSize="13dp" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Shanesh Colors"
            android:id="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_3" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_2"
            android:textSize="13dp" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:textColor="#000000" />
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text=" App Account "
            android:id="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_4" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_3"
            android:textSize="13dp" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/login_rellay_04" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:gravity="center" android:layout_below="@+id/login_rellay_03"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="#FFFFFF" android:id="@+id/imgv_page1_6"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />



    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/login_rellay_04" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp">
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="User Name:"
            android:id="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_5" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_1"
            android:textSize="11dp" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="#49515F" />

        <EditText android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>



    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/login_rellay_05" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_rellay_04">
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:text=" Password:"
            android:id="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_5" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_1"
            android:textSize="11dp" 
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="#49515F" />

        <EditText android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_5" />



    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/login_rellay_06" 
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_rellay_05" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:textColor="#000000"
                  android:text="No Account?"

                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:textSize="11dp" 
                  android:id="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_9" 

                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:text="Sign Up" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:id="@+id/login_txvx_signup_account" 
      android:textColor="#8891A2" 
      android:textStyle="bold" 
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/login_txvx_dwbnr_9"
      android:textSize="11dp" 
     /></RelativeLayout>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/login_rellay_07" 

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_rellay_06" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

     <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/login_txvx_signup_account"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:textColor="#49515F" 
            android:textSize="11dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text=" Remember User Name and Password?" 
      />

      </RelativeLayout>





</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/login_rellay_08" 

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_rellay_04" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

      <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:src="@drawable/page1_8"
                 />
      </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot used fixed dimensions if your aspect ratio or screen sizes are expected to vary.  That is why Java focused on layout managers to be more platform agnostic than previous Windows development methods which forced dimensions.  Forced dimensions are bad.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your tablet width is more than 306. so the banner is showing at center of the screen but taking width required for the banner image. try following

you are using

android:layout_width="wrap_content"

for ImageView in which you are setting your banner

please try using

android:layout_width="match_parent"

instead. Another way is try to put big size banner image in /drawable-xlarge folder to match your tablet screen size